# Not Able to Resolve View Using Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have put all jsp on classpath in views folder.

Folder structure is :

```
src/main/resources/
src/main/resources/static/
src/main/resources/static/views/
src/main/resources/static/views/*.jsp
src/main/resources/static/views/*.png
```

I am able to retrieve images file from static folder. But When It comes to jsp I am getting following error.

While hitting url:`http://localhost:9001/login`

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/views/login/login.jsp
```

However login.jsp exists on given location.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was supposed to use war as packaging. Jar packaging does not work in case of jsp.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can place your JSP files in "src/main/resources/META-INF/resources" folder location.

I have created a "WEB-INF/jsp" folder under "src/main/resources/META-INF/resources" and placed the JSP file there.It works. Check the screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3jUI.png

2. Alternatively, You can create "WEB-INF/jsp" folder under "src/main/webapp" and placed the JSP file there.But for this you have to package it as ".war" extension.

Comment: how can i padkage it as war from gradle ?  apply plugin: 'war' ?

Answer (score 1):

*Springboot* default tomcat container does not handle *JSP*. so we need to use below dependency to handle it :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And if you are using *JSTL* tags in *JSP* then add below jar as well :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

A template such as a JSP is the exact opposite of static content such as an image file. Put your template in `src/main/resources/templates`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put them in folder :

`src/main/resources/templates`

2.These three dependencies could help you:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Actually I was trying using jar. But There is no support of running application using boot with jsp. So we need to deploy war in tomcat.

Comment: First, change packaging in your pom.xml to:
    '<packaging>war</packaging>'. 
To create war:
    `mvn package`
Then change `spring-boot-starter-tomcat and tomcat-embed-jasper` scope to provided `<scope>provided</scope>`, copy war tomcat and start server.
If you don't put `provided` as scope you might no be able to deploy it to Tomcat but you would be able to run it like a jar with command: java -jar yourApp.war

Answer (score -1):

I believe by default Spring Boot looks for html files. To change that behavior you have to change your `application.properties` as following to use jsp-s: `spring.view.suffix: .jsp`

Maybe even change `spring.view.prefix` as well to point to static resources.

I would personally suggest to use html-s with Thymeleaf though.